# Pattern matching loses type bounds?

Tags: scala

Why isn't `effects` an `Effect[A]`? The types should line up from `foo`.

http://scastie.org/20029

```
/***
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

*/
trait Effect[A]

sealed trait ActionResult[+M, +A] {
}

sealed trait ModelUpdated[+M] extends ActionResult[M, Nothing] {
}

sealed trait HasEffect[+M, +A] extends ActionResult[M, A] {
}

sealed trait UpdateSilent

object ActionResult {

  case object NoChange extends ActionResult[Nothing, Nothing]

  final case class ModelUpdate[M](newModel: M) extends ModelUpdated[M]

  final case class ModelUpdateSilent[M](newModel: M) extends ModelUpdated[M] with UpdateSilent

  final case class EffectOnly[A](effect: Effect[A]) extends ActionResult[Nothing, A] with HasEffect[Nothing, A]

  final case class ModelUpdateEffect[M, A](newModel: M, effect: Effect[A]) extends ModelUpdated[M] with HasEffect[M, A]

  final case class ModelUpdateSilentEffect[M, A](newModel: M, effect: Effect[A])
    extends ModelUpdated[M] with HasEffect[M, A] with UpdateSilent

  def apply[M, A](model: Option[M], effect: Option[Effect[A]]): ActionResult[M, A] = (model, effect) match {
    case (Some(m), Some(e)) => ModelUpdateEffect(m, e)
    case (Some(m), None)    => ModelUpdate(m)
    case (None, Some(e))    => EffectOnly(e)
    case _                  => NoChange
  }
}

object Main {
  def foo[A, B]: ActionResult[A, B] = ???
  def dispatch[A, B] = {
    foo[A, B] match {
      case ActionResult.NoChange =>
        false
      case ActionResult.ModelUpdate(newModel) =>
        false
      case ActionResult.ModelUpdateSilent(newModel) =>
        true
      case ActionResult.EffectOnly(effects) =>
        true
      case ActionResult.ModelUpdateEffect(newModel, effects) =>
        val e: Effect[A] = effects
        false
      case ActionResult.ModelUpdateSilentEffect(newModel, effects: Effect[A]) =>
        true
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: don't you mean `val e: Effect[B] = effects`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer per say, but here are some thoughts. First of all, I've simplified and clarified your code example to minimize down to the problem:

```
trait Effect[A]
trait ActionResult[+M, +A]
trait ModelUpdated[+M] extends ActionResult[M, Nothing]
trait HasEffect[+M, +A] extends ActionResult[M, A]

case class ModelUpdateEffect[M, A](newModel: M, effect: Effect[A]) extends ModelUpdated[M] with HasEffect[M, A]

object Main {
  def foo[M, A]: ActionResult[M, A] = ???
  def dispatch[M, A] = {
    foo[M, A] match {
      case ModelUpdateEffect(newModel, effect) =>
        val e: Effect[A] = effect // does not compile                                                              
        false
      case _ => true
    }
  }
}
```

Let's note the error message we get for that line:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Effect[Any]
 required: Effect[A]
Note: Any >: A, but trait Effect is invariant in type A.
```

It's kind of strange the compiler decides that `effect` has type `Effect[Any]`. But let's see what happens if we replace this definition:

```
case class ModelUpdateEffect[M, A](newModel: M, effect: Effect[A]) extends ModelUpdated[M] with HasEffect[M, A]
```

with this:

```
case class ModelUpdateEffect[M, A](newModel: M, effect: Effect[A]) extends HasEffect[M, A]
```

Now we get a different error message:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Effect[?A1] where type ?A1 <: A (this is a GADT skolem)
 required: Effect[A]
Note: ?A1 <: A, but trait Effect is invariant in type A.
```

In this case, the types really don't match up right. Let's walk through it. We know from outside the `case` statement that we have an `ActionResult[M, A]`. But because of the covariance on the type param `A`, that `ActionResult[M, A]` may well be an `ActionResult[M, B] forSome { type B <: A }`. In other words, there may be some type `B` that is a sub-type of `A`, and `foo[M, A]` might return an `ActionResult[M, B]`. In which case, `effect` would be an `Effect[B]`, and because the type parameter for `Effect` is invariant, this type is not compatible with `Effect[A]`.